# How can I find all the types that have not inherited from anything in my code via Reflection in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection

I have some classes that inherit from a base class and I have other classes that inherit from nothing:

```
public class SomeDerivedClass : BaseClass
```

and

```
public class FreeFromInheritanceClass
{
}
```

I want to find `FreeFromInheritanceClass` and other classes like it.

I tried this code but iI want to find `FreeFromInheritanceClass` and other classes like it.

I tried this code but it does not work:

```
typeof(Program)
.GetTypes()
.Where(i => i.BaseType == null)
```

I found out that my `FreeFromInheritanceClass` in fact inherits from `System.Object`.

So, how can I find the classes that do not inherit from anything?t does not work:

```
typeof(Program)
.GetTypes()
.Where(i => i.BaseType == null)
```

I found out that my `FreeFromInheritanceClass` in fact inherits from `System.Object`.

So, how can I find the classes that do not inherit from anything?

Comment: `FreeFromInheritanceClass` is inherited from `object`

Comment: `.Where(i => (new Type[] {null, typeof(object), typeof(ValueType), typeof(Enum)}).Contans(i.BaseType))`

Answer (score 1):

Every class (and struct actually) is [`System.Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=net-8.0) in .NET so check for base type being object:

> Supports all classes in the .NET class hierarchy and provides low-level services to derived classes. This is the ultimate base class of all .NET classes; it is the root of the type hierarchy.

And from the [specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#823-the-object-type):

> The `object` class type is the ultimate base class of all other types. Every type in C# directly or indirectly derives from the `object` class type.
> The keyword `object` is simply an alias for the predefined class `System.Object`.

So `FreeFromInheritanceClass` actually inherits from `System.Object`, so to find it with reflection you can to check for `BaseType == typeof(object)`:

```
var res = typeof(Program)
    .Assembly
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(i => i.IsClass && i.BaseType == typeof(object))
    .ToArray();
```

If you also need user-defined structs then you can add `i.BaseType == typeof(ValueType)` or just check for `IsValueType` (`IsEnum` for enums):

```
var res = typeof(Program)
    .Assembly
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(i => i.BaseType == typeof(object) || i.IsValueType)
    .ToArray();
```

As [@Dmitry Bychenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2319407/dmitry-bychenko) mentioned in comments `i.BaseType == null` check will work for interfaces without base ones.

Note that output may contain some compiler generated classes so you might want to exclude them (usually they have `<`, `>` symbols in their names, so you can filter based on that).

Comment: `BaseType` can be `null` when `type` is an interface; it can be `Enum` if `type` is `enum`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thank you already fixed wording a bit which should cover that.